# Take $M$ balls from a box with $N$ balls

Tags: combinatorics

It's been a while since I last touched combinatorics. Given a box with $N$ balls, $R$ reds, $G$ greens and $B$ blues (so $R+G+B=N$). We are going to take out $M$ balls from the box. How many ways are there to do it?

If all the balls were different then it will be easy ${N \choose M}$. But all balls with the same color are the same. So how can I do it?

Comment: If $M \leq \min\{R, G, B\}$, then you need to find the number of solutions of the equation $r + g + b = M$ in the nonnegative integers, which is a [combination with repetition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination#Number_of_combinations_with_repetition) problem.  If $M > \min\{R, G, B\}$, you can apply the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle to eliminate those cases that violate the restrictions.

Answer (score 1):

We can solve this problem with an algebraic form of the PIE, derived from generating functions. We are looking for $[x^m]\frac{1-x^{R+1}}{1-x}\cdot \frac{1-x^{G+1}}{1-x}\cdot \frac{1-x^{B+1}}{1-x} = [x^m]\frac{1-x^{R+1}-x^{G+1}-x^{B+1}+x^{R+G+2}+x^{G+B+2}-x^{R+G+B+3=N+3}}{(1-x)^3}$

Which is equivalent in closed form to ${m+2 \choose 2}-{m+1-R \choose 2}-{m+1-G \choose 2}-{m+1-B \choose 2}+{m-R-G \choose 2}+{m-G-B \choose 2}+{m-B-R \choose 2}-{m-R-G-B-1 \choose 2}$. (Recall that the binomial coefficient ${n \choose k}$ for $k<0$ or $k>n$ is equal to 0.)